# How to call a function in an Obj-c++ file from an Obj-c file?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have a .m file which recently had to include a reference to a C++ namespace, meaning I needed to rename it to have a .mm extension. This seemed to work fine, but now, unrelated function calls are having linker errors. Previously I had the following in my header with no issues:

```
void CMLogMessage(NSString *Message, ...);
```

Once I changed the corresponding .m file to .mm, I now get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_CMLogMessage", referenced from:
  (Code References From .m Files Here)
```

My best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting C++ name mangling. Declare the function to have C linkage:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void CMLogMessage(NSString *message, ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```